# How can I "IP-enable" a KVM?

Tags: keyboard-video-mouse

So, I have a KVM, specifically a [Belkin OmniView 8-Port USB/PS2](http://catalog.belkin.com/IWCatProductPage.process?Product_Id=379164). This is in a 1/3 private locking cabinet (colo). This is for my own personal use so I am dealing with very low budgets.

I would really like an IP KVM so that I can troubleshoot remotely. Belkin sells an [OmniView SMB Remote IP Device](http://catalog.belkin.com/IWCatProductPage.process?Product_Id=375082) for $630 that will add the IP functionality to this unit.

However, that seems like a waste of money to me, because I can [buy a brand new IP-enabled KVM for only $730](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817394062&cm_re=ip_kvm-_-17-394-062-_-Product). So $100 more gets me a whole new unit, plus it's only one device to maintain.

My question: **is there any other way to "IP-enable" an existing KVM**? For instance, could I get a 1-port IP-KVM (like [this one](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817707162&cm_re=ip_kvm-_-17-707-162-_-Product) for $315) and just attach the IPKVM to my old, non-IP KVM? Or are there any software solutions?

I realize this is a very specific question, but I would love to avoid spending $600 if possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd make sure that the new IP KVM and your existing KVM don't use the same meta key to do things.  Otherwise you'll need to do something clever to make sure that the right device gets the signal.  Sadly, I know this one from experience.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't gotten to use one of these [OpenGear IP-KVM](http://www.opengear.com/product-IP-KVM.html) devices yet, but they look awesome. They're relatively inexpensive ($345.00), and can be attached to existing KVM switches (see http://www.opengear.com/product-IP-KVM-diagrams.html) or directly to server computers.

Comment: That looks awesome. Wants. But their online store is down, and nobody else (Amazon, NewEgg, Google Shopping) seems to carry them. If you find a working purchase link, please drop it in a comment. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be working: http://www.opengearstore.com/category_s/4.htm

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are no software options, because the device needs to be able to send keyboard/mouse commands and receive VGA video, which is not something a standard computer can do.

That single-port IP-KVM unit should be fine, just make sure that you know what the keyboard shortcuts for your KVM are (often it's related to the Print-Screen button) so that youc an send them over the IP device.

Answer (score 1):

Many vendors have built-in solutions that solve the KVM issue.  For example, Dell has DRAC cards that have a separate network interface and a web-GUI to provide console access - relatively speaking they are quite inexpensive.  That might be an option for you.